# How to throw error in Post

Tags: javascript, java

I want to check if the `name` already exists on the database. So I will do a Post. Let's assume the name already exists.

How do I throw an error so it shows an error in the html, using the error: function of the ajax?

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");

    //Check if name exists and return true or false
    if(exists)
        throw error to ajax
    }
    //else save data
}

//Ajax Post
$('#btnSubmit').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'GeneralSetup',
        data: data,
        success: function () {
            window.location.href = "/clients.jsp";
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On the server it's enough to send the http response code of 4XX(client error) or 5XX(server error).
In your case you can use `response.sendError(400)` - meaning bad request. 
[List of HTTP status codes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 1):

We can do two ways

1. 1)change responsecode to 4xx and append to response paramter
2. 2)pass    information to frontend by using response paramter

   @Override
       protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
           String name = request.getParameter("name");

   ```
       //Check if name exists and return true or false
       if(exists)

           response.setStatus(4XX)
           or
           PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
           writer.println("userAlready is Exist");

       }
       //else save data
   }

   //Ajax Post
   $('#btnSubmit').click( function() {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: 'GeneralSetup',
           data: data,
           success: function (data) {

             if(data =='userAlready is Exist' && data!=null){
                $('#some Div TAg Id').html(data);
            }else{
            //write redirect code
              window.location.href = "/clients.jsp";
           }
           },
           error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               var errorMsg = 'Ajax request failed: ' + xhr.responseText;
                 $('##some Div TAg Id').html(errorMsg);
           }
       });
       return false;
   });
   ```

Comment: response parameter goes to sucess function right? What about the redirect? I want to redirect IF there is no repeated name.

Comment: Update the answer check it now !!